# How to Alias a namespace and extend the original namespace based on the alias

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++14

I have the current problem in C++:

I have a namespace for a given external library. I didn't like the name of this external namespace, so I did this following:

```
namespace mynamespace = othernamespace;
```

and this works fine if I want to say do the following:

```
mynamespace::foo(...);
```

but I found that I needed to have a special function to convert values found in `othernamespace` to values found in an external library.   I defined a function the following way:

```
Y xToY(mynamespace::X x);
```

I realized I only wanted to use this function in the context of `mynamespace`, and I still didn't like using the namespace name for `othernamespace` so I thought simple, I would do the following:

```
namespace mynamespace = othernamespace;

namespace mynamespace{
    Y xToY(mynamespace::X x);
}
```

however I get the following compiler error telling me that this can't be done:

```
myheader.h:13:11: error: namespace alias 'mynamespace' not allowed here, assuming 'othernamespace'
```

and thus it doesn't compile.  Note I'm currently using c++14.  I would like to know if it is possible for me to extend this namespace using my alias name for the namespace `othernamespace`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. It's unfortunately not possible. The rule, from [namespace.def], explicitly excludes aliases:

> In a *named-namespace-definition*, the identifier is the name of the namespace. If the identifier, when looked up (3.4.1), refers to a *namespace-name* **(but not a *namespace-alias*)** that was introduced in the
>   namespace in which the *named-namespace-definition* appears or that was introduced in a member of the inline namespace set of that namespace, the *namespace-definition* *extends* the previously-declared namespace.
>   Otherwise, the identifier is introduced as a *namespace-name* into the declarative region in which the *named-namespace-definition* appears.

You cannot extend a namespace by alias, you can only extend a namespace by the original namespace name.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind putting how to properly extend an arbitrary namespace?   I think that would improve this answer and help any one else stuck with the same issue, SO doesn't seem to have a post discussing how to actually extend a namespace, so including something like `namespace namespacename{ signature}` for header and `returntype namespacename::signature(...){}` in cpp would be useful for people understanding how to do this.

Comment: @snb I don't understand the question. You just do `namespace the_namespace_name { ... }`.

Comment: I know how to do it, but I'm asking you to provide an example of how to do extend a namespace since no examples of that exist explicitly on stack overflow, I didn't know you could extend arbitrary namespaces until recently, and there aren't many resources that actually go about explaining how you would do it in the simplest case, most just go into "you can add variables" but with out cpp definition it can be confusing as to why an extension isn't working (in the real example I had, I misnamed the function but thought I was simply not using correct syntax even after using no alias)

Answer (score 3):

Do it by building a new namespace, rather than an alias:

```
// external namespace

namespace othernamespace {

    struct X {};
    void foo(X& x) {};
}

// my namespace

namespace mynamespace
{
    using namespace othernamespace; // equivalent to import * from othernamespace
}


int main()
{
    mynamespace::X x;

    foo(x);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem at all, I just end up writing more code in this version with no benefit.  I wanted to refer to the namespace by an *alias* and add new functionality to the *same namespace*, not create a new one. Note with the @Barry's answer I switched the namespace extension to use the real name, but when i call the respective function I can still use the alias I chose to refer to that namespace.